# Creating an AppiumDriver with http

Tags: java, apache, selenium, proxy, appium

I'm looking for a way to instantiate an instance of AppiumDriver while passing in an instance httpClientFactory. This has been modified in the past few versions of Appium.

Is there an example on how to create an instance of org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient.Factory httpClientFactory while authenticating with a Proxy server with credentials?

Here's the method signature

```
public AppiumDriver(java.net.URL remoteAddress,
                    org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient.Factory httpClientFactory,
                    org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities desiredCapabilities)
```

[Here's](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.html) is the Full Javadoc for AppiumDriver

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve that would be to use the **HttpCommandExecutor**.

You could try following code snippet (using appium java-client 7.0.0):

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(host, port);

CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(host, port), new NTCredentials(user, password, workstation, domain));

builder.setProxy(proxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
Factory factory = HttpClient.Factory.createDefault();
HttpCommandExecutor executor = new HttpCommandExecutor(new HashMap<>(), remoteAddress, factory);

AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver<>(executor, desiredCapabilities);
```